# primefaces autocomplete when cleared field giving previuos results of page on clicking submit button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using an autocomplete tag of prime faces which retrieves results from a database.

The problem is that when I submit the form leaving the autocomplete field empty the results I get on the page are those of the previous request (the previously selected autocomplete value) - it only gets cleared when I refresh the page.

I want that on each submit, without refreshing the browser page, if i clear out the value in the field using backspaces and submit the form it should give the correct result for this particular instance, not previous one.

I am also using some textfields in the jsf page form but those don't have this problem.
Can anyone offer guidance as to how this problem can be corrected?

**EDITED:**
Code:

```
<h:form>
  <h:dataTable id="Ressult" value="#{input.searchResults}" var="r">
    <h:column>#{r.ID}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{r.Name}</h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
  <tr>
    <td>Current Education Level</td>
    <td>
      <h:panelGrid styleClass="text-box">
        <p:autoComplete id="education" value="#{input.education}"
        completeMethod="#{input.getautocomplete}" var="a"
        itemLabel="#{a.Name}" itemValue="#{a}"
        converter="edConverter" forceSelection="true" />
        <p:column>#{a.Name} - #{a.id}</p:column>
      </h:panelGrid>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>
      <h:selectOneMenu id="txtCity" styleClass="select-field"
      value="#{input.cityId}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel=" Please Select" itemValue="0">
        </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItems value="#{input.cities}"></f:selectItems>
      </h:selectOneMenu>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name of Person</td>
    <td>
      <h:inputText id="txtName" value="#{input.nameOfPerson}"
      styleClass="text-box"></h:inputText>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <h:commandButton id="btnSearch" value="Search"
  action="#{input.searching}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="Ressult"></f:ajax>
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

And here is the bean code:

```
public class Input 
{
    private Education education;
    private List<SelectItem> cities;
    private Integer cityId;
    private String nameOfPerson;
    private List<Results> searchResults;
    //getters and setters

    public String searching()
    {
         searchResults=dao.getSearchResults(cityId,education,nameOfPerson);
         return "success";
    }

    public void autocomplete(String query)
    {
        //AUTOCOMPLTE lIST CODE HERE
    }
}
```

By update, if you mean new results to be shown when new items selected, then yes - the form should be updated but autocomplete somehow takes the previously selected value and shows results according to that. At least until I refresh the page - only then is autocomplete's previous is removed.

Comment: are you updating the form ?? and please post code in order to get more help..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my autocomplete widget.
When I removed its id attribute it worked. Maybe a bug in Primefaces.

Answer (score 1):

You may have two things to do:

1. Prevent the user from submission by pressing the Enter key by doing the following in your form:

   ```
   <h:form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
   ```
2. Using itemSelect/itemUnselect features provided to empty the field in the Bean:

   ```
   <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
       listener="#{autoCompleteBean.handleSelect}" global="false"
       update=":some:where" />

   <p:ajax event="itemUnselect"
       listener="#{autoCompleteBean.handleUnselect}" global="false"
       update=":some:where" />

   <!-- rest of your facelet stuff -->
   ```

In the Bean:

```
public void handleSelect(final SelectEvent event) {
    final Search search = (Search) event.getObject();
    // do your addition here
}

public void handleUnselect(final UnselectEvent event) {
    final Search search = (Search) event.getObject();
    // do your substraction here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the onkeypress hint solved a difficult problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Well if i understand your question correctly your list of auto completion is shown after the post. And you use your form to submit time after time to the same page.

Your bean looks a little bit odd. Because you're calling in the page the autocomplete method: getautocomplete but that one doesn't exists in your bean.

Use the autocomplete in this way:

```
<p:autoComplete id="education" value="#{input.education}"  completeMethod="#{input.autocomplete}" var="a" itemLabel="#{a.Name}" itemValue="#{a}" converter="edConverter" forceSelection="true" />
```

And in your bean:

```
public List<Education> autocomplete(String query)
{
        List<Education> educations = new ArrayList<Education>();
        //search with query in your dao something like:
        educations = dao.searchEducation(query);

        return educations;
}
```

Comment: yes this is whats smthng like this happening in my autocomplete method which i didnt added previously beacause thought it was understandable. the autocomplete works fine , it does retrieves values from db. problem is when on same page if i resubmit form using new value it shows previous results on list. can this behaviour be removed of previous state saved on resubmition??

Comment: Post the code of your complete bean. It's now guessing what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

fixed on 5.2, upgrade your primefaces jar

here the log issue

https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7592

Comment: same problem also with 5.2

Answer (score 0):

To fix the subject issue you just remove the forceselection

or make it as false.

Answer (score 0):

Just process event to server. Works with forceselection="true"

```
<p:ajax event="itemUnselect" global="false" />
```